# complexity of foo algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, complexity-theory

I have this problem that I can't solve.. what is the complexity of this foo algorithm?

```
int foo(char A[], int n, int m){
  int i, a=0;
  if (n>=m)
    return 0;
  for(i=n;i<m;i++)
    a+=A[i]  
  return a + foo(A, n*2, m/2);
}
```

the foo function is called by:

```
foo(A,1,strlen(A));
```

so.. I guess it's log(n) * something for the internal for loop.. which I'm not sure if it's log(n) or what..

Could it be theta of log^2(n)?

Comment: no, this is an exam I've done today, and I'm trying to understad if I did it right (I doubt it..)
Please, maybe it's not super appropriate to ask here, but I've asked at cstheory.stackexchange and they said I should ask here.

Comment: i don't think there's a problem with asking questions from schoolwork, it's just etiquette (i believe) to make it very clear that it is

Comment: Relying on case-sensitivity is bad (`a` and `A` are both defined) as this lowers code readability, relevance of code search results, etc… Also, the value of `m` should be calculated inside of the function itself for DRY coding. Then, you are dividing an integer while you don't know its value. Next to that all, assuming this is C, there is a syntax error on the `a+=A[i]` line. And last but not least, there is no check for the size of the values of `n` and `m` the first time, so a stack overflow can occur easily when `m` is huge and `n` is tiny. Bad code. Can't believe this appeared on an exam.

Comment: ahah! You're right! And this is quite good compared to others.. still that's what we have..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great application of the master theorem:

Rewrite in terms of n and X = m-n:

```
int foo(char A[], int n, int X){
  int i, a=0;
  if (X < 0) return 0;
  for(i=0;i<X;i++)
    a+=A[i+n]  
  return a + foo(A, n*2, (X-3n)/2);
}
```

So the complexity is

```
T(X, n) = X + T((X - 3n)/2, n*2)
```

Noting that the penalty increases with X and decreases with n,

```
T(X, n) < X + T(X/2, n)
```

So we can consider the complexity

```
U(X) = X + U(X/2)
```

and plug this into master theorem to find U(X) = O(X) --> complexity is O(m-n)

Comment: @luca It occurred to me that not everyone has been exposed to the introductory algorithms text informally referred to as CLR : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a 'quick and dirty' way, but you can use old good math. No fancy theorems, just simple equations.

On k-th level of recursion (`k` starts from zero), a loop will have `~ n/(2^k) - 2^k` iterations. Therefore, the total amount of loop iterations will be `S = sum(n/2^i) - sum(2^i)` for `0 <= i <= l`, where `l` is the depth of recursion.

The `l` will be approximately `log(2, n)/2` (prove it).

Transforming each part in formula for `S` separately, we get.

```
S = (1 + 2 + .. + 2^l)*n/2^l - (2^(l + 1) - 1) ~= 2*n - 2^(l + 1) ~= 2*n - sqrt(n)
```

Since each other statement except loop will be repeated only `l` times and we know that `l ~= log(2, n)`, it won't affect complexity.

So, in the end we get `O(n)`.